# Convert SQL with CASE to Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

How can I complete the following in access

```
SELECT MONTH([Date]) as monthNum, 
AVG(CASE WHEN loc ='1' THEN  [Count] END) AS locAVG, 
AVG(CASE WHEN dept ='50' THEN  [Count] END) AS deptAVG, 
FROM [table]
GROUP BY MONTH([Date])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`IIF`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx) in this case;

```
AVG( IIF(loc = "1", 1, 0) ) AS locAVG,
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `[Count]` is the name of a field and you want `locAVG` to be the average of `[Count]` for the rows where `loc ='1'`, you can take advantage of the fact that the `AVG()` function ignores Null values.  So use an `IIf()` expression to feed `[Count]` to `AVG()` when `loc ='1'` but Null otherwise.

Use a similar `IIf()` expression for `deptAVG`.

```
SELECT MONTH([Date]) as monthNum, 
    AVG(IIf(loc ='1', [Count], Null)) AS locAVG, 
    AVG(IIf(dept ='50', [Count], Null)) AS deptAVG, 
FROM [table]
GROUP BY MONTH([Date]);
```